# Copy the link to clipboard in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Here below the code I have saved like **'/Document/filename.txt'** If I clicked copy table  the link should be copied to clipboard

```
$('#select').on('change',function(){
    var criteria=$('#criteria :selected').val()
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{id,},
        datatype:'json',
        success:function(result)
        {
                var html='';
                $.each(result, function (key,items) {
                    html+= '<td>'+items.id+'</td>'
                    html+= '<td><a  href='+criteria.naac_document+'><i   class="fa fa-download" title="Download"  style="font-size:20x;color:red"></i></a></td>'
                    html+='<td><a href='+criteria.naac_document+'  onclick="copyURI(event)"><i   class="fa fa-copy" title="Download"  style="font-size:20x;color:red"></i></a></td>'
                    html+='</tr>';
                });
                $('.tbody').html(html)
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: do you want to copy the link of current page  ?

Comment: @ShabbirVaghela  current row href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ***copyURI(e)*** function should looks like this:

```
function copyURL(e){
  let $temp = $("<textarea>");
  $("body").append($temp),
  $temp.val(e).select(); 
  document.execCommand("copy"); 
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach eventHandlers to the newly loaded data, with something like this. Add the class 'loadedLink' to the new links too:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    $("a.loadedLink").on("click", copyURI(e));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.execCommand("copy")` and a temporary `input`.

**Working example:**

```js
function copyURI(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var temp_input = $("<input>");
  
  $("body").append(temp_input);
  temp_input.val(event.target.href).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  temp_input.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a  href='http://test-url' onclick="copyURI(event);">click to test</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input placeholder="paste it here">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

HTML:

```
<div class='your_class' data-clipboardtext='your data'></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery('.class_name').on("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    value = jQuery(this).data('clipboardtext');
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(value);
    
});
```